# can't connect to mysql with a host

Tags: mysql, mariadb, database-connection

I have mariadb installed and running.

I can connect to it with this:

`mysql -u dev -p`

or

`mysql -h localhost -u dev -p`

but I can't connect to it using

`mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u dev -p`

It asks me for my pwd, which I enter. but after that it just hangs.

I need to be able to connect with `127.0.0.1` because I am using jdbc and I want to make connection using that.

Answer (score 3):

MySQL will sometimes treat '`localhost`' as a reference to the local socket i.e: `/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock` instead of the network address `127.0.0.1`

First, you should edit the MySQL config file `my.cnf`

Change the following line:

```
socket = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

To:

```
bind-address = 127.0.0.1
```

And restart mysqld, `service mysqld restart`

If you are still having problems, make sure to check your firewall rules to see if there is anything preventing access to/from `127.0.0.1:3306`

Comment: I don't have `/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock` file. When I turn off iptables then I can make the connection to 127.0.0.1 so I think it has to do with iptables. But even when I open port 3306 I can't connect. This is a AWS box.